# How to delete Cookies from windows.form?

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I am working with the Webbrowser control on a windows.form application written in C#. I would like to write a method for deleting the cookies from the Webbrowers control after it visits a certain site. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that exactly and haven't found a lot of help on the internet.

If anyone has experience actually doing this, not just hypothetical because it might be trickier than it seems, I don't know.

```
int count = webBrowser2.Document.Cookie.Length;
webBrowser2.Document.Cookie.Remove(0,count);
```

I would just assume something like the above code would work but I guess it won't. Can anyone shed some light on this whole cookie thing?

Comment: I'm curious.  Would setting the object "webBrowser2" to a new instance of the WebBrowser control reset the cookies?

Comment: No, you physically have to delete them. It's just a matter of knowing the correct directory to look and catching access denied exceptions for files in use

Comment: I know what a cookie is.  I need to delete a specific cookie.

Comment: The HtmlDocument.Cookie documentation says that you can only set a single cookie at a time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have JavaScript enabled you can just use this code snippet to clear to clear the cookies for the site the webbrowser is currently on.

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())")
```

It's derived from [this bookmarklet](http://ostermiller.org/bookmarklets/cookies.html) for clearing cookies.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you need to be able to clear cookies for all sites, you're probably better off using something like the axWebBrowser COM object. .NET's built in WebBrowser control is pretty locked down. 

I only used this when switching to axWebBrowser wasn't an option and the browser only needed to be able to browse one site.

Comment: thank you sir .. i was looking for a code like this for ages .. thank thank

Comment: Note: HttpOnly cookies are not available to javascript.

Answer (score 18):

I modified the solution from here:
http://mdb-blog.blogspot.ru/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html

Actually, you don't need an unsafe code. Here is the helper class that works for me:

```
public static class WinInetHelper
{
    public static bool SupressCookiePersist()
    {
        // 3 = INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST 
        // 81 = INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR
        return SetOption(81, 3);
    }

    public static bool EndBrowserSession()
    {
        // 42 = INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION 
        return SetOption(42, null);
    }

    static bool SetOption(int settingCode, int? option)
    {
        IntPtr optionPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        int size = 0;
        if (option.HasValue)
        {
            size = sizeof (int);
            optionPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);
            Marshal.WriteInt32(optionPtr, option.Value);
        }

        bool success = InternetSetOption(0, settingCode, optionPtr, size);

        if (optionPtr != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.Release(optionPtr);
        return success;
    }

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
        int hInternet,
        int dwOption,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        int dwBufferLength
    );
}
```

You call SupressCookiePersist somewhere at the start of the process and 
EndBrowserSession to clear cookies when browser is closed as described here:
[Facebook multi account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206199/facebook-multi-account)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too, ended hours of research why my ADFS server was always stuck on login to the same Claims Provider Trust, even after a logout.

Comment: This somewhat works for me on Windows 10, in that subsequent usages of the browser do not have cookies, but when I restart the program and don't set INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST, old cookies show up again. So it doesn't seem to actually delete the cookies, as noted in mr.baby123's answer

Comment: According MSDN [Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.alloccotaskmem?view=net-5.0) should be released with [Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(IntPtr)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freecotaskmem?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_FreeCoTaskMem_System_IntPtr_) .

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution, for deleting all cookies.
the example found on the url, deletes the cookies on application (process) startup.

> http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html

The solution is using [InternetSetOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Function to announce the WEBBROWSER to clear all its content.

```
int option = (int)3/* INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST*/;
int* optionPtr = &option;

bool success = InternetSetOption(0, 81/*INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR*/, new IntPtr(optionPtr), sizeof(int));
if (!success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong !>?");
}
```

Note, that clears the cookies for the specific PROCESS only as written on MSDN [INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR):

> A general purpose option that is used to suppress behaviors on a
>   process-wide basis.

Answer (score 4):

A variant of other proposed answers, which doesn't require unsafe code or manual marshalling:

```
    private static void SuppressCookiePersistence()
    {
        int flag = INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST;
        if (!InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR, ref flag, sizeof(int)))
        {
            var ex = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    const int INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR = 81;
    const int INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST = 3;

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, ref int flag, int dwBufferLength);
```

Comment: And with the new (C# 7.2) `in` parameter modifier, you don't even need the extra `flag` variable , you can just specify inline: `InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR, INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST, sizeof(int));` if you declare the p/invoke as `internal static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, in int lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);`

Comment: On a related note, no, this doesn't delete the cookies. This modifies the policy so that even cookies normally marked as persistent will not be persisted. Thread cautiously because using it might break some sites and login processes. If it works in your case then the cookies will be gone after you leave all right but it might just not work.

Answer (score 4):

web browser control based on Internet Explorer , so when we delete IE cookies,web browser cookies deleted too. so by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863770/6899111) answer you can try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","/C RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies.ToString() + "cookiename");
```

Comment: This won't always work. Sometimes, the browser control uses randomly-named files to stoke cookies

Comment: This will attempt to delete a file named "Cookiescookiename"... probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Does the webbrowser control show pages form mutliple sites that you, as a developer, are not in control of, or are you just using the web browser control to view custom HTML pages created within your application?

If it is the former, cookies are directly tied to the domain that sets them, and as such to delete these cookies you would need to monitor the users's cookie directory and delete any new cookies created, a track changes to existing cookies.

If it is the later, you can always send the webbrowser control to a custom page that deletes the cookies with either server-side scripting (if available in your application) or JavaScript.

Comment: I guess the WebBrowser control doesn't use something like a CookieContainer object that we can just reset to reset all cookies, eh?

Comment: Well, I read somewhere on google that webbrower control cookies are stored in some application cache seperate from IE. I don't mind deleting all the cookies from the cookies folder in windows but I'm just not sure if that will solve the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, that could be the case currently. The last time I used a WebBrowser Control was with VB6 of all things, so they certainly may have refined that by now. I wouldnt delete all the users cookies though, in any case. Thats just mean. I stored my passwords to naughty sites in those cookies. =)

Comment: Great, well let me test your suggestion out and see if it will work, if so I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 1):

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code and it works without JavaScript.  It's doing the same things as the JavaScript, but in VB.NET.  Also, no navigation needed.

```
For Each cookie As String In Document.Cookie.Split(";"c)
    Dim domain As String = "." + url.Host
    While domain.Length > 0
        Dim path As String = url.LocalPath
        While path.Length > 0
            Document.Cookie = cookie.Split("="c)(0).Trim & "= ;expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT;path=" & path & ";domain=" & domain
            path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 1)
        End While
        Select Case domain.IndexOf(".")
            Case 0
                domain = domain.Substring(1)
            Case -1
                domain = ""
            Case Else
                domain = domain.Substring(domain.IndexOf("."))
        End Select
    End While
Next
```

The only real difference from the JavaScript is where, instead of just expiring `cookie=value`, I specifically search for the `=` and expire `cookie=`.  This is important for expiring cookies that have no value.

Pitfalls:

- You can only delete the cookies of the website to which you have navigated.
- If the page is redirected to a different domain, the cookies you remove might be from the redirected domain.  Or not, it's a race between the redirect and your code.
- Don't access `Document` until `ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`, otherwise Document will be Nothing and the dereference will throw an exception.
- Probably lots of others, but this code works great for me.

Firefox with the [View Cookies Add-On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/315) helped a lot in debugging specific web pages.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution for cookies visible to Javascript.  But not for HttpOnly cookies.

Answer (score 0):

After a great time finding how destroy sessions in webbrowser C# I'm have sucessfull using a code:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())")
```

how says for Jordan Milne in this topic above.

In my application I need use webbrowser1.navigate("xxx");

here don't work if you use the C# properties.

i hope you find it useful this information.