# Any way to tell the WebBrowser control to start in 'nomerge' mode if user has IE8

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

Our application uses a webbrowser control on a form to navigate to our website when a certain action is performed on our 'text-based' legacy application.

All was fine in IE5, 6 and 7 but now it appears IE8 shares session cookies not only between tabs in the same intance but also between all instances.  This is a major bother if a user wants to have two separate instances looking at different client details at the same time.

One can disable the latter behaviour by starting IE with the command line switch -nomerge.

Does anybody know how we can achieve the same effect *programatically with the WebBrowser control*?

Thanks in advance chaps.

Comment: Cannot really help here but would be interested too. I recently found out how to disable that annoying click sound (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393166/how-to-disable-click-sound-in-webbrowser-control) and maybe this will give you a starting point to find a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335617/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-ie-in-a-windows-form

Comment: Not quite.  Thanks for pointing it out but the question was ambiguous enough to have only got answers that don't quite satisfy our requirements.  The answer given by Franci Penov was closest but we need both sessions separate not a single session that invalidates the 'previous' session.