# How do I use INTERNET_HANDLE_TYPE_INTERNET to constrain the effects of END_BROWSER_SESSION to the current WebBrowser?

Tags: c#

We have a WebBrowser that needs to have login information reset.

There is a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335617/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-ie-in-a-windows-form) question that suggests using `INTERNET_HANDLE_TYPE_INTERNET` with `INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION`. However, I'm not sure where `INTERNET_HANDLE_TYPE_INTERNET` should go.

```
private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;
private const int INTERNET_HANDLE_TYPE_INTERNET = 1;

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, 
    IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
```

I call it right before I navigate:

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 
    0);              
browserCtrl.WebBrowser.Navigate(loginUrl);
```

Comment: You cannot get that handle from WebBrowser.  I seriously doubt IE still uses WinINet.  Try creating a new instance of WB instead.

Comment: That's the problem, even when you create a new instance of WB, it retains the login session information. Using INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION solves this problem, but I'm concerned it will affect other applications like Office.