# How Classic ASP Session works in deeply

Tags: browser, asp-classic

I know that the ASP Session use some cookie identifiers. But I wan't to know how deeply it identify the browser and what browser is in the right session.

The ASP Sessions keep working even if you disable browser cookies, so how it work's, and what exactly are the variables needed to ASP identify a browser in the right session, like remote IP + Cookie + some header sent by the browser to keep the identification session, please elucidate me.

Some example is this question: [Opening a new window create a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472407/opening-a-new-window-create-a-new-session)

When the browser open a new window using Javascript it keep the cookies but lost the ASP session reference (even with the cookies still in there).

But if you just open a new window (or tab), the session will remain there.

Comment: +1 For taking this to a question of its own.  It might be good if you explictly explain the exact method used to discover this loss of an ASP Session, how do you go about determining the session is actually lost?  Perhaps a small but complete example of code that you are using.

Comment: Also what is the version of IIS you are using to test with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good article explaining the Session object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx

Some additional sources of info:

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-manage-a-session-across-multiple-windows.html

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-won-t-my-session-variables-stick.html

Comment: +1 Yes, and explain the ASP creating new sessions however the cookie already exists on the browser, but not explain why this happens with javascript open windows function.

Comment: Gabriel, I don't believe that sessions are lost when javascript opens a new window. I use this all the time on my application and there is no session loss. Can you explain in your question further why you feel sessions are lost?

Comment: @MikeMurko it's about this topic friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472407/opening-a-new-window-create-a-new-session

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: Well, to answer the question I felt all three links were needed.  Too much to try and recap in this instance. When possible I write a specific answer to a specific question.  It's just not always possible.  Thanks for following my work.