# Delete all WebBrowser cookies and session data also set referer

Tags: c#, wpf, cookies, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, Webbrowser control: How to delete Cookies from windows.form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/c-webbrowser-control-how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form)

How can i delete all of the session data and cookies of webbrowser1 element in C# 4.0 WPF application.

Also second question is how do i set referrer when navigating an url?

```
<WebBrowser Height="474" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="354,85,0,0" Name="webBrowser1" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="785" Grid.Row="1" />
```