# Deleting cookies in WPF web browser control

Tags: wpf, cookies, webbrowser-control

I am developing a WPF application in which I am working with twitter API. To show twitter authentication page I am using WPF web-browser control. I am able to login and use twitter API successfully. My problem is that I need to clear web browser's cookies to implement logout functionality. Is there any way to clear session cookies in WPF web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/860d1b66-23c2-4a64-875b-1cac869a5e5d

```
private static void _DeleteSingleCookie(string name, Uri url)
    {
        try
        {
            // Calculate "one day ago"
            DateTime expiration = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            // Format the cookie as seen on FB.com.  Path and domain name are important factors here.
            string cookie = String.Format("{0}=; expires={1}; path=/; domain=.facebook.com", name, expiration.ToString("R"));
            // Set a single value from this cookie (doesnt work if you try to do all at once, for some reason)
            Application.SetCookie(url, cookie);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Assert.Fail(exc + " seen deleting a cookie.  If this is reasonable, add it to the list.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ponmalar, Thanks for replying. I have already tried that link but that didn't worked for me. I believe that method described there clears persistent cookies not session cookies. I need to clear session cookies. May be that clarifies the problem.

Comment: did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/c-webbrowser-control-how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue yesterday and finally came up with a full solution today. The answer is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921878/2789877) which is put into more detail [here](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.ca/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html) and [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/InternetSetOption.html).

The primary issue here is that the `WebBrowser` (in WPF and WinForms) does not permit you to modify (delete) existing session cookies. These session cookies are what prevent a multi-user single device experience from being successful.

The StackOverflow response in the link above omits an important part, it requires the use of an unsafe code block, instead of using the `Marshal` service. Below is a full solution that can be placed into your project to suppress the session cookie persistence.

```
public static partial class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);

    private const int INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR = 81;
    private const int INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST = 3;

    public static void SuppressCookiePersistence()
    {
        var lpBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST, lpBuffer, true);

        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR, lpBuffer, sizeof(int));

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lpBuffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I think the best way would be to define a Javascript method on the page (if you're able to) that clears the cookie.

```
document.cookie='c_user=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;domain=.facebook.com';
```

(or whatever the cookie name is).  Then you can use the [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx) method on the *WebBrowser* control.

Comment: dbaseman, Thanks for reply, I am using twitter API to access twitter, so I don't think I can define a javascript method on that page, or did I misunderstood something? If I am right, then is there any other way to do that?