# msal.net prompt behaviour with social idp

Tags: .net, azure-ad-msal

I have wpf application where I'm acquiring token using msal.net.

I want to force the user to input credetials everytime. I understand that this can be achieved with Prompt.ForceLogin however this doesnt seem to work for social idps. Is there something I'm missing or is this not supported?

Only I have been able to get this behaviour is with InternetSetOption as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810881/deleting-cookies-in-wpf-web-browser-control)

Here's the msal code

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithB2CAuthority(authorityEndpoint)
                .Build();

var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
                .ExecuteAsync();
```