# How do I remove cookies for one website on the C# web browser on visual studio?

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make a little C# program that loads a website and clears all the cookies for that website when a button is pressed.

It could also just clear all the cookies in general if that's easier.

I've been using the standard visual studio web browser but if anyone knows of a better way to do this I'll happily use that. I tried everything in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form) and nothing worked.

Comment: You want to delete all the current cookies for your application instance, or for example if they opened it in Chrome or Internet Explorer you want to clear those cookies too?

Comment: Just for the application instance if possible, but if it needs to delete the cookies for IE too that's not a big deal.