# How can I delete the cookies for a C# web browser?

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make a little C# program that loads a website and clears all the cookies for that website when a button is pressed.

It could also just clear all the cookies if that's easier.

I've been using the standard visual studio web browser but if anyone knows of a better way to do this I'll happily use that. I tried everything in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form) and nothing worked. I'd prefer to do this as a website instead of a program but I'd need to show another website inside my website and be able to delete the client's cookies for the other website. Any ideas?

Comment: do a google search on how to create Cookies as well as how to Delete Cookies..

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search returned MSDN page which explains how to delete a cookie.

1. Determine whether the cookie exists, and if so, create a new cookie with the same name.
2. Set the cookie's expiration date to a time in the past.
3. Add the cookie to the Cookies collection object.

The following code example shows how to set a past expiration date on a cookie.

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
   HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
   myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
   Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Of course you'll use this in your **[Button.Click Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

**[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)**