# How to clear C# App cookies

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies, httpwebrequest

i have an C# WindowsForm Application.
this Application get response from the target website.
the target website is sensitive on cookies.i mean when i use different IP to connect to the target website if i removed browser cookies, target website know me as a new user and if i don't the target website know me as previous user.
now i want get response from the target website by my Application.
this is the main part of my Application(that get response from sites which doesn't sensitive on cookies)

```
            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(SiteBox.Text);
            Req.Proxy = new WebProxy(Proxy.ToString());
            Req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36";
            StreamReader Res = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
            Res.ReadToEnd();
            Res.Close();
```

How i can remove App cookies after response

Comment: Unclear what you want/asking. If the site you're trying to access requires authentication, then you _must_ (authenticate). Cookies are one way that web sites persist "sessions" so you don't have to "login" on each protected resource it provides.

Comment: look, i want increase view of this site by the application,
using a list of IPs(the above code is in a loop) and i want to remove cookies after every time that my loop execute so next time that loop execute the target website know me as a new viewer
and the cookie is only thing that prevent me to do it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing before which you wanted to do. but unfortunately I can't remember it. You can check links on my comment, maybe it will be helpful

[on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form)

[on msdn forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71a5b2bb-f254-45b3-94a0-d194e335211c/how-to-clear-webbrowser-control-cookie-in-c?forum=winforms)