# how to delete cache. cookies in c# web browser

Tags: c#, cookies

I wanted to delete the cache and cookies of a C# web browser..

I uses the following code in `formload` method, but it is not working

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())");
}
```

please tell me how to fix this issue.

about code is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete Cookies from windows.form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form)

Comment: i did like that,but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The **WebBrowser** control is like an Interface of **IE**. If you want to clear Cache/Cookies in a meaningful way then you'll have to call the **IE APIs** for that. Otherwise you could use another User Control like **Selenium** which could give better results.

You can also refer to: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/71a5b2bb-f254-45b3-94a0-d194e335211c/how-to-clear-webbrowser-control-cookie-in-c?forum=winforms

and as @pmcilreavy suggested:
[How to delete Cookies from windows.form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form)

Selenium:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium

Comment: you sent same link i proffered. i got the code from here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form

Comment: did you try calling the corresponding IE API for deleting the cache/cookies?