# How to clear Web Browser cache -context Store in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the Web Browser control to display a Login page for user to signing to their account and then application will get contacts from that account.

However, the problem is if user select option "Keep signing" from browser, browser will cache that account name and next login with different account, it will return previous cached account name. This lead to application will get wrong account name.

You guys know how to force WebBrowser to clear all cache context Store before proceed to prevent this problem?

Comment: Are you using OAuth for signing into their account?

Comment: No Token based validate Product

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Cookies from windows.form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form)

Comment: Bro Asking about WPF Not in Windows Platform. We Check That Solution also Its Not Supported.

Comment: We are Try to Delete Like Application inside - Applicaiton -> context Store Values Entirely through C# once the Login process done. Now Its not Clear that why.